# OrderSend mq4 ea

Tags: mql4

I'm projecting a EA for SELL LIMIT adn BUY LIMIT operation. It's quite simple. The MT4 must open the order (or more than one) at a specific price. Here is my code with 2 pending orders

```
    void OnTick(){

    if (OrdersTotal()==0)
    int sellticket_0 = OrderSend
    (Symbol(),OP_BUYLIMIT,0.12,"0.73870",0,"0.73552","0.73893",NULL,0,
    TimeCurrent()+167552,clrGreen);

    if (OrdersTotal()==1)
    int sellticket_1=OrderSend
    (Symbol(),OP_BUYLIMIT,0.12,"0.73683",0,"0.73552","0.73813",NULL,0,
    TimeCurrent()+167552,clrGreen);
    }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: 1. prices should be passed as doubles ( 1.23456 ) not as a string ("1.23456"); 2. most brokers use ECN approach - put an order first with entry price, if successfully - modify with SL and TP.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. If I'd like to specify the asset I must put EURUSD or "EURUSD" instead of Symbol()?

Comment: When I use symbol() it opens automatically AUDUSD. If I specify another asset (for example EURUSD) it doesn't work

Comment: "EURUSD" for a particular symbol. `Symbol()` replaces it with the name of the chart/backtest symbol, so apply the script to EURUSD chart not AUDUSD chart if you have `Symbol()`